# Try to install ubuntu 18.04 to HP Laptop 1-da0xxx

Tags: 18.04

I'm trying to install the Ubuntu 18.04 to my laptop HP Laptop 15-da0xxx
it is possible to my laptop. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully installed 18.04 to two seperate HP da0xxx model laptops. I had no issues installing from live cd or bootable usb. I have to re-install quite often on one of them, due to my inexperience and and tendency to make mistakes. I have not had a single issue out of the 20 plus installs I have done. I am not sure that it matters, but I did a customization on the partitions from different suggestions I have found across the web. You may have to change some settings in your BIOS/EFI. I did, as the factory settings would not initially allow it. If you are asking the question, I would imagine you have attempted it and had no luck. You should try giving specifics in your question so that the answers can help you in detail. I hope this helps.